# How can I tell Jhipster to only use ES6 for Angular/React apps?

Tags: angular, reactjs, jhipster

Currently when I create a project using jhipster I see it generates angular/react apps using TypeScript. Is there a way to tell it to only use ES6 without TypeScript when running the script  ?

Comment: Post the contents of your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: JHipster generates only Typescript code.

Comment: Oh OK! thanks @GaëlMarziou